# Wagtail: how to restrict all pages to logged in users only

Tags: wagtail

I am using Wagtail for an internal knowledge base. I would like all pages to default to 'Accessible to logged in users'.

This is possible on a page-by-page basis using the 'privacy' setting: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/advanced_topics/privacy.html

How can I make this the default for all pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The privacy settings are inherited by all child pages so if you make your Homepage accessible to logged in users then all its children (i.e *all pages*) will also have the same privacy setting! Notice that by "Homepage" I mean the root page of your wagtail tree ie the first page that you see to its right after you click "Explorer" in wagtail admin (on single site wagtail setups).

Comment: but how do you make your homepage accessible to only logged in users?

Comment: I haven't used Wagtail in quite some time however the docs (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/privacy.html) say that there should be a "Privacy" control in the top right corner of each page. Just set this to "Accessible to only logged in users" for your homepage.